# Firefox and FCKeditor not rendering cftextarea - only on one computer

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, fckeditor, cfml

I have one computer in our network that will not render the cftextarea in Firefox 41.0.2.  Firebug console shows the following only on that particular computer;

```
SyntaxError: missing } after function body fckeditorcode_gecko.js:108:329
ReferenceError: FCKConfig is not defined fckconfig.js:27:1
ReferenceError: FCKBrowserInfo is not defined fckeditor.html:125:1
ReferenceError: FCKConfig_LoadPageConfig is not defined fckeditor.html:164:1
ReferenceError: FCKTools is not defined fckeditor.html:176:5
ReferenceError: FCK_ContextMenu_Init is not defined fckeditor.html:195:1
ReferenceError: FCKLang is not defined fckeditor.html:203:1
ReferenceError: FCKBrowserInfo is not defined fckeditor.html:270:1
ReferenceError: InitializeAPI is not defined
```

This does not happen on other computers (all Windows 7).

I'm stumped!

UPDATE:

I can go through a list of emails to go out (in a particular app) and after about three records I get a blank textarea.  If I hold down the shift key and click on the refresh icon (on the url bar) the textarea goes completely away.  There is some kind of place holder because the area for the textarea is a big blank. Now any textarea on any other page is blank.  It reminds me of a virus spreading.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ctrl-F5 to refresh the page, the textbox/editor comes back up.  Who knew?